# Can't execute a `print` statement

Tags: python

Why do I keep getting an error?

My code:

`prin(hey)`

I have tried many ways and watched many YouTube videos but it's not working for me.

I tried it without `()` but it still doesn't work.

Sorry if my English is bad.

Comment: it's print('hey')  or print("hey").  Note the letter (t) at the end and then the quotes holding the hey. What error do you get?

Comment: "Why do I keep getting an error?"—well, what does the error _say?_ "An error" tells us nothing. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because print is spelt wrong and if you want hey as a string you have to do put it in quotes.

Try this

`print('hey')`